# How do I set the default page of my website as index.html?

Tags: apache

I'm making my company's website and I work on the FTP via Filezilla. But, even though I already have a page named index.html to be the homepage, when I open my website in the browser it is not set as the default page.

I read on some forums that this setting must be made by apache, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `DirectoryIndex` directive in your Apache configuration must contain (among potential others) `index.html`

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html

But it's usually the default setting, so make sure your file is actually named `index.html` and not `Index.html`, `index.HTML` or any other case variant because *nix servers are case sensitive.